# Querying XMl with Indexed path

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file and I would like to query that using indexed path. I am not sure if it is even possible but any help is very much appreciated !

So what I am looking for is to be able to query the xml file with a path something like this.

ReturnState[0]\ReturnDataState[0]\Form6[0]\Body[0]\Member[0]\FormA1

Should give me the FormA1 under the first Member element. There are numerous reasons for this approach and without getting into too much details, I would like to know if querying something like this is even possible using xpath or any other way.

```
<ReturnState> 
  <ReturnDataState>
    <Form6>    
      <Body>     
        <Member>
          <MemberName>
            <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Mouser0</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
          </MemberName>
          <FormA1>
            <PartI-SalesFactor>
              <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754631</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>
              <TotalSales>
                <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
              </TotalSales>
              <SalesFactorTotal>
                <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
              </SalesFactorTotal>
              <ApportionmentPercentage>0.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
            </PartI-SalesFactor>
          </FormA1>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <MemberName>
            <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Mouser1</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
          </MemberName>
          <FormA1>
            <PartI-SalesFactor>
              <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754632</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>
              <TotalSales>
                <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>1965873633</TotalCompany>
              </TotalSales>
              <SalesFactorTotal>
                <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>196587344</TotalCompany>
              </SalesFactorTotal>
              <ApportionmentPercentage>1.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
            </PartI-SalesFactor>
          </FormA1>
        </Member>
        <Member>
              <MemberName>
                <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Mouser2</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
              </MemberName>
              <FormA1>
                <PartI-SalesFactor>
                  <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754632</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>
                  <TotalSales>
                    <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                    <TotalCompany>1965873633</TotalCompany>
                  </TotalSales>
                  <SalesFactorTotal>
                    <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                    <TotalCompany>196587344</TotalCompany>
                  </SalesFactorTotal>
                  <ApportionmentPercentage>1.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
                </PartI-SalesFactor>
            </FormA1>
        </Member>
        <Member>
          <MemberName>
            <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Mouser3</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
          </MemberName>
          <FormA1>
            <PartI-SalesFactor>
              <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754632</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>
              <TotalSales>
                <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>1965873633</TotalCompany>
              </TotalSales>
              <SalesFactorTotal>
                <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>196587344</TotalCompany>
              </SalesFactorTotal>
              <ApportionmentPercentage>1.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
            </PartI-SalesFactor>
          </FormA1>
        </Member>
     </Body>
    </Form6>
  </ReturnDataState>
</ReturnState>
```

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: Do you really mean for your title to say XMI (rather than XML)?

Comment: I only asked as XMI is a valid tag and if it wasn't a typo then you should add the tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath has it's own specification that you need to follow, and it is not much different from the path expression you currently have. Some differences that matter here are, XPath index starts from `1` isntead of `0`, and path separator in XPath is `/` instead of `\`. Better to adjust your path expression slightly to conform to the XPath syntax, unless you are happy to implement your own parser :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_your_file.xml");
var xpath = "ReturnState[1]/ReturnDataState[1]/Form6[1]/Body[1]/Member[1]/FormA1";
var result = doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yoyaAr)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<FormA1>
  <PartI-SalesFactor>
    <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754631</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>
    <TotalSales>
      <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
      <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
    </TotalSales>
    <SalesFactorTotal>
      <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
      <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
    </SalesFactorTotal>
    <ApportionmentPercentage>0.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
  </PartI-SalesFactor>
</FormA1>
```

Comment: Thanks Har07 for the quick reply. Really appreciate it !!